# We want to hide out of stock products from Magento2, which is already enabled with MSI

Tags: magento2

We want to hide out of stock products from one of my Magento2 project, which is already enabled with MSI.
But we are unable to do the same.. Any help will be appreciable..

Comment: ...and then what?

Comment: we are unable to hide.. plz help us..

Answer (score 0):

In Admin Panel you can disable showing out of stock products:

Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options -> Display Out of Stock Products -> No

Comment: tried, but with Multi source inventory, this is not working for configurable products.